# How do I get Value-at-Risk for a GED distribution in R?

Tags: garch, distribution, kurtosis

I need to calculate parametric Value-at-Risk using a GARCH model assuming a GED distribution. How can calculate it in R?
thank you

Answer (score 1):

### VaR for GED in R

```
package(fGarch)
qged(p, mean = 0, sd = 1, nu = 2)

#Example
qged(.01, mean=1000, sd=2000)
[1] -3652.696
```

where, $1-p$ is confidence level.

Comment: GED distribution is assumed for standardized errors, but these will be scaled by the conditional standard deviation as per the GARCH model to form the real errors. The question is (I believe), what is the VaR for the real errors? If VaR is just a quantile, I suppose one should just multiply the argument `sd` in the function `qged` by the conditional standard deviation at the particular data point.

Comment: @RichardHardy It is not clear in the question, so I provided basic answer.

Comment: That's fine, I just thought you might want to improve your answer by adding a paragraph on the case when the *standardized* errors are GED. This is the case here, I believe (I found a similar question by the same user at Cross Validated, hence I knew what he was looking for.)